# How to calculate required frictional force required to prevent rotation of hollow cylinder?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

Imagine a scenario where you have a hollow cylinder and you press this hollow cylinder down onto some surface (lets imagine its in the x-y plane) such that it is not rolling but its cross section is flat against the surface. You have a friend that comes by and tries to rotate this cylinder (around the z-axis) from underneath you while you are pressing down.

How can I calculate how big the moment around z needs to be to rotate this hollow cylinder given the axial force being used to push down onto this cylinder.

Lets assume the cylinder is infinitely stiff and ignore its mass for now, just looking at the external forces involved.

What I would like clarity on is the physics behind what is happening at the interface between the hollow cylinder and the surface, specifically once you convert the force applied to the cylinder axially to a frictional force using F<sub>f</sub> = μF<sub>n</sub>, how do you find the radius at which to apply the shear force induced by the friend trying to rotate the cylinder? Is there surface area and thus pressure equations involved here or not?

UPDATE: Adding picture for clarity. F<sub>A</sub> is the axial force being applied. M<sub>Z</sub> is the moment being induced.

[image]

Comment: How do you apply a torque, without applying a force on hollow cylinder where you cannot grab hold of the center?

Comment: Not sure I follow, you can grab the outside of the cylinder and attempt to rotate it which would create a moment around the z-axis in this case.

Comment: I thought the cylinder was lying down. Thank you for the picture. Again, applying a _pure_ torque isn't easy without some net force on the plane trying to accelerate the center of mass.

Comment: Yep totally agree there, just using the scenario as a way to establish the question. For this example I think it makes sense that the friend is applying pure torque and I am looking for a way to connect this torque value to the axial force applied. Just struggling to see the set of equations thta would describe what is happening at the interface at the bottom of the cylinder and plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the problem here does not have a unique solution, because it assumes a certain distribution of contact pressure, and the more outwards biased this distribution is the more torque capacity you have.

For a sufficiently thin hollow cylinder you can ignore all that and just assume that contact pressure exists on the radius $R$ only.

If the applied force is $F_A$, then each little piece of the cylinder in contact spanning an angle ${\rm d}\theta$ will carry a vertical force ${\rm d}F = F_A \frac{{\rm d}\theta}{2 \pi}$. The available traction force due to the vertical force is ${\rm d}T = \mu {\rm d} F$, and each traction creates a torque about the centerline ${\rm d}M_z = R {\rm d}T$. The total torque is

$$ M_z = \int_0^{2\pi} (\mu F_A) R \tfrac{1}{2 \pi} {\rm d}\theta = \mu R F_A $$

So if the applied torque $M_z$ is above this value, the cylinder is going to move, and if it is below it is going to stay put.

---

For completion, I am going to include the equations below that need to be satisfied for a general pressure distribution $P(r)$ that depends on the radius, as it spans $r = R_{i} \ldots R$

$$\begin{aligned}
  F_A & = \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_{R_i}^R P(r) \;r {\rm d}r {\rm d}\theta \\ M_z & = \int_0^{2 \pi} \int_{R_i}^R \mu P(r) \;r^2 {\rm d}r {\rm d}\theta \end{aligned}$$

Take for example a constant pressure distribution $P(r) = P_0$ which yields

$$\begin{aligned} 
  F_A &= \pi P_0 \left( R^2 - R_{i}^2 \right) \\
  M_z & = \tfrac{2}{3} \pi P_0 \mu \left( R^3 - R_{i}^3 \right)
\end{aligned}$$

which is solved for

$$\begin{aligned} 
  P_0 & = \frac{F_A}{\pi \left( R^2 - R_{i}^2 \right)} \\
  M_z & = \tfrac{2}{3} \mu F_A \frac{ R^2 + R R_i + R_i^2}{R+R_i}
\end{aligned}$$

when $R_i \rightarrow R$ then $M_z = \mu R F_A$ as we saw above. Also for a sufficiently thin cylinder with $R_i = R - t$, then $M_z \approx \mu F_A \left( R - \tfrac{t}{2} \right)$

Comment: Thanks for diving deep into this, the result derived then represent what would be a general equation of Torque due to the assumption of a sufficiently thin hollow cylinder. Could you expand your definition of Mz to include a hollow cylinder now that is not sufficiently thin and has some inner diameter d, and outer diameter D? What would this intergral look like or how can we redefine R here to capture scenarios outside of the sufficiently thin assumption? UPDATE: Anwesered that question! TY!

Comment: This is exactly what I have done above, with inner radius $R_i$ and outside radius $R$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no force big enough to stop it from rolling. Static friction at the interface of the rolling surface only helps it to roll and not slip.

Rolling friction does not work the same way as sliding friction, and in this case there would be 0 rolling friction because you specified the cylinder is infinitely stiff. In real life rolling friction occurs because the material deforms and therefore absorbs kinetic energy as heat as it rolls.

Comment: Added a picture to clarify the scenario, I believe you assumed the cylinder was rolling.